# Get Videos from a Channel using Youtube API V3 in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-api, youtube-channels, youtube-data-api

I have a ASP.Net webpage where I was displaying Youtube Videos from my channel using V2. Since Google has retired V2 API, I am trying to use V3 API, but unable to get the videos from the channel.

I did look at the samples at github, but the example shows how to create a video, but no way to retrieve videos. Searching on SO, I see examples using php library, I am looking something specific to C#.

Can anyone help me with regard to this?

Comment: playlist isn't the same as a channel @LitisqeKumar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding channel id to [Search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)  it returns a list of the videos in the channel.

```
var searchListRequest = service.Search.List("snippet");
searchListRequest.ChannelId = "UCIiJ33El2EakaXBzvelc2bQ";
var searchListResult = searchListRequest.Execute();
```

**Update response to comment explanation to what is happening:**

Actually search returns everything associated with the channel id, you are after all searching on a channel id.

Search returns a SearchListResponse which contains a number of items.   Each item is of type [SearchResource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource) search resources can have different types or Kinds.  In the two pictures below you can see that the first one is kind `youtube#channel` the second is kind `youtube#video` it will be up to you to loop though them and find the youtube videos.  if you scroll to the bottom of the search.list page you can try it and see the raw JSon that the API is returning.

[image]

[image]

**solution:**

Now if all you want to do is get the videos back you can just tell it that all you want are videos by adding type to your request:

```
searchListRequest.Type = "video";
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: go for it I tested it before I posted.  https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/YouTube you have any problems I can upload the change to the sample project

Comment: @DalmTo it does return result, but it returns a PlaylistID and iterating over .Items property is not giving correct results. Any insights?

Comment: hows that wall of text :)

Comment: Amazing...I checked my ChannelId and it returns Itemtype of Kind "youtube#searchResult". I am trying to figure it out further.

Comment: do you have the latest nugget package? seams I am using 1.9.0.1300 looks like there is a newer one I could try and update mine.  no change I still get a "youtube#searchListResponse"

Comment: I figured it out, Thanks

Comment: DalmTo, is this the correct link?
https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Samples/YouTube%20Data%20API

Comment: @IrishChieftain yes thats the most resent build of my samples.  Let me know if you are having any issues with it.

Answer (score 5):

Although asked some time ago I also have been searching for a while how to get videos ( all ) from channel using C#. At the moment I have method that supports pagination (probably can be done better :) )

Hope this helps

```
    public Task<List<SearchResult>> GetVideosFromChannelAsync(string ytChannelId)
    {

        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            List<SearchResult> res = new List<SearchResult>();

var _youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = "AIzaXyBa0HT1K81LpprSpWvxa70thZ6Bx4KD666",
            ApplicationName = "Videopedia"//this.GetType().ToString()
        });

            string nextpagetoken = " ";

            while (nextpagetoken != null)
            {
                var searchListRequest = _youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
                searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                searchListRequest.ChannelId = ytChannelId;
                searchListRequest.PageToken = nextpagetoken;

                // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
                var searchListResponse = searchListRequest.Execute();

                // Process  the video responses 
                res.AddRange(searchListResponse.Items);

                nextpagetoken = searchListResponse.NextPageToken;

            }

            return res;

        });
    }
```

Comment: What is _youtubeService in your example?

Comment: can we differentiate videos on a  play list channel using this method?

Comment: @Priyankara could you elaborate what do you mean  ?

Comment: @erPe I meant that using this method we can get all the video details of a channel. if we want to get only a play list details of a channel, can we use this approach?

Comment: @Priyankara I havent played this way but take a look on the API documetnation as this is all based on those. So if API supports it you would be able to do it

Comment: @erPe ok sure. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Hi, I'm not expert in c#...can somebody write the part of the app that call and show to console the method? Very thanks

Comment: @erPe can you help me?

Comment: @n3o You can see the accepted answer. It provides all details. What is it that you exactly struggle with ?

Answer (score 0):

In a youtube channel, there are lots of playlists. Under each playlist there are lots of videos. So at first, I brought out playlist then from each playlist I brought out video lists. So here is my solution which I implemented in my project. This is a complete code to get videos from a youtube channel and display the videos like a youtube channel  with information like how many days ago the video posted etc. Here I also implemented caching to load videos faster.  It takes me a lot of time to implement this. Hope it will help.

Model :

```
    public class VideoViewModel
    {
        public List<PlayList> PlayList { get; internal set; }
    }


    public class PlayList
    {

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public List<VideoList> VideoList { get; set; }


    }

    public class VideoList
    {

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string PublishedDate { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult Index(string VideoId, string VideoType, int? PageNo)
    {

     VideoViewModel ob = new VideoViewModel();
     ob = GetFromList();
     return View(ob);

    }


     VideoViewModel GetFromList()
     {

        VideoViewModel ob = new VideoViewModel();
        IDatabase cache = Connection.GetDatabase();
        string serializedVideos = cache.StringGet("");
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(serializedVideos))
        {
            ob.PlayList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PlayList>>(serializedVideos);

        }
        else
        {

            GetYoutubeVideosFromApi(ob);
            cache.StringSet("", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ob.PlayList));


        }
        return ob;
    }


    public void GetYoutubeVideosFromApi(VideoViewModel ob)

    {
        ob.PlayList = new List<PlayList>();
        WebClient wc = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
        try
        {
            string jsonstring = wc.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&key=yourkey&maxResults=50&channelId=yourchaneelid");

            JObject jobj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);

            foreach (var entry in jobj["items"])
            {
                PlayList pl = new PlayList();


                pl.Title = entry["snippet"]["title"].ToString();
                pl.Description = entry["snippet"]["description"].ToString();
                pl.Id = entry["id"].ToString();
                pl.VideoList = new List<VideoList>();
                string jsonstring2 = wc.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=" + entry["id"].ToString() + "&key=yourkey&maxResults=50");

                JObject jobj2 = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring2);

                foreach (var vl in jobj2["items"])
                {
                    VideoList v = new VideoList();
                    v.Title = vl["snippet"]["title"].ToString();
                    v.Description = vl["snippet"]["description"].ToString();
                    v.Id = vl["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"].ToString();
                    v.Url = vl["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["medium"]["url"].ToString();

                    var publishTime = vl["snippet"]["publishedAt"].ToString();
                    var temp = DateTime.Parse(publishTime);
                    v.PublishedDate = GetTimeInMonth(temp);

                    pl.VideoList.Add(v);

                }

                ob.PlayList.Add(pl);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }


    public static string GetTimeInMonth(DateTime objDateTime)
    {
        const int SECOND = 1;
        const int MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
        const int HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
        const int DAY = 24 * HOUR;
        const int MONTH = 30 * DAY;

        var ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - objDateTime.Ticks);
        double delta = Math.Abs(ts.TotalSeconds);

        if (delta < 1 * MINUTE)
            return ts.Seconds == 1 ? "one second ago" : ts.Seconds + " seconds ago";

        if (delta < 2 * MINUTE)
            return "a minute ago";

        if (delta < 45 * MINUTE)
            return ts.Minutes + " minutes ago";

        if (delta < 90 * MINUTE)
            return "an hour ago";

        if (delta < 24 * HOUR)
            return ts.Hours + " hours ago";

        if (delta < 48 * HOUR)
            return "yesterday";

        if (delta < 30 * DAY)
            return ts.Days + " days ago";

        if (delta < 12 * MONTH)
        {
            int months = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 30));
            return months <= 1 ? "one month ago" : months + " months ago";
        }
        else
        {
            int years = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 365));
            return years <= 1 ? "one year ago" : years + " years ago";
        }

    }


     private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        string cacheConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheConnection"].ToString(); 
        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(cacheConnection);
    });

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyConnection.Value;
        }
    }
```

View: It actually depends on how you want to display the video list.